# Any idea where to get unvoiced speech data?

Tags: audio, signals, speech, voice-detection

As we have 2 main classes of speech..i.e. voiced and unvoiced. I have been able to test my method with voiced. e.g. a recorded vowel /a/. but i want to see the output when i use unvoiced speech. Could someone point me to a database of these type of speech data?

Comment: Doesn't unvoiced just refer to consonants where the vocal chords are not engaged? For example "p" (unvoiced) versus "b" (voiced)? What are you using for voiced consonants? Voiced sibilants and fricatives?

Comment: @PhilFreihofner yes thats what unvoiced sounds are. But i just want a '.wav' speech file of these consonants to try out. There are so many voiced sounds but ive never come across the unvoiced ones strangely.